# android read json utf-8 text file

Tags: android

How i can convert my code into "utf-8"?i have a text file which name is "textarabics.txt"
and this text file contains utf-8 characters..below is my code please suggest me how i can convert into utf-8?

```
 try {
        File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "textarabics.txt");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        String jsonStr = null;
        try {
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

            jsonStr = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
            Log.d("Noga Store", "jString = " + jsonStr);
          }
          finally {
            stream.close();
          }

             Log.d("Noga Store", "jString = " + jsonStr);
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting data JSON Array nodes
            JSONArray data  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            // looping through All nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString("id");
                String title = c.getString("title");
             //   String duration = c.getString("duration");
                int duration = c.getInt("duration");

                // tmp hashmap for single node
               /* HashMap<String, String> parsedData = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                parsedData.put("id", id);
                parsedData.put("title", title);
                parsedData.put("duration", duration);*/

                textnames.add(title);
                textduration.add(duration);
            //    textnames.add(duration);
                // do what do you want on your interface
              }


       } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

This is my "textarabics.txt" file

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "تخطي نوجا نوجا أخبار واستعراض السوق",
        "duration": 10
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "أحدث نوجا الأخبار وآخر المستجدات",
        "duration": 3
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "نوجا الأخبار وآخر المستجدات",
        "duration": 5
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "لا تحتوي على تطبيقات وجد نوع الكلمة",
        "duration": 7
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "تحتاج إلى إعادة تشغيل التطبيق لاتخاذ تغييرات الخط. هل تريد إعادة التشغيل الآن",
        "duration": 4
    }
]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Charset.defaultCharset()` you can use `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`. Also you are missing a JSONTokener that you should use with your input. This is based on your code:

```
       try {
            File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "textarabics.txt");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            String jsonStr = null;
            try {
                FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

                jsonStr = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(bb).toString();
                Log.d("Noga Store", "jString = " + jsonStr);
              }
              finally {
                stream.close();
              }

                 Log.d("Noga Store", "jString = " + jsonStr);
                         // A JSONTokener is needed in order to use JSONObject correctly
                 JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(jsonStr);
                         // Pass a JSONTokener to the JSONObject constructor
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);


                // Getting data JSON Array nodes
                JSONArray data  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                // looping through All nodes
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                 //   String duration = c.getString("duration");
                    int duration = c.getInt("duration");

                    // tmp hashmap for single node
                   /* HashMap<String, String> parsedData = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    parsedData.put("id", id);
                    parsedData.put("title", title);
                    parsedData.put("duration", duration);*/

                    textnames.add(title);
                    textduration.add(duration);
                //    textnames.add(duration);
                    // do what do you want on your interface
                  }


           } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

A more efficient way of dealing with the file would be to wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `InputStreamReader` and using [InputStreamReader with charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor appending the characters to read to a StringBuffer.

Another solution - working on Android 11+ is

```
    try {
        File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "textarabics.txt");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        try {
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);
            jsonReader.beginObject();
            jsonReader.nextName();
            jsonReader.beginArray();
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                jsonReader.beginObject();
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                    String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {

String id = jsonReader.nextString();
// use the id parameter in some way
                        System.out.println("id = " + id);
                    }
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
String title = jsonReader.nextString();
// use the title parameter in some way
                        System.out.println("title = " + title);
                    }
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("duration")) {
// use the duration parameter in some way
int duration = jsonReader.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("duration = " + duration);
                    }
                }
                jsonReader.endObject();
            }
            jsonReader.endArray();
            jsonReader.endObject(); 
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
                reader = null;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            try {
                if(stream != null) {
                    stream.close();
                }
                stream = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What crash are you getting? The second question is what is the size of the file?

Comment: 02-24 16:25:47.269: W/System.err(23692): org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @FarhanShah what android version are you targeting? I modified your code and posted it in my answer (I used a different file name and changed it now so it is the same as in your example) the code I am using works in android 11+ (3.0 and up). you have to add the imports though. I tried it on the exact String you posted in your sample.

Comment: bro still not working..please chnage update my question which i have posted if u can please..

Comment: What are you getting as a result? Is it an exception? What exception are you getting? The code I posted is an implementation that works without a problem on the exact file you posted. If you are getting an exception - what is it?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.JsonReader and many more

Comment: @FarhanShah see the updated answer with a modified version of your code

Comment: bro thanks alor for ur support,but still same issue and same crash,at this line my app crash   JSONArray data  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data"); and says     org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Did you use the exact code I posted in my answer? you have to change this line of code JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(jsonStr);
                         // Pass a JSONTokener to the JSONObject constructor
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);

Comment: check the data you are using - if it is the exact String you have posted then it should work, except if the data is wrong in the file

Comment: can you post me the exact code somewhere? as a project?

Comment: @FarhanShah can you add the code to your question? It seems really strange for the code in the beginning of my answer not to work with the exact file content you posted.

Comment: sorry bro for late reply..were i can send my project?

Comment: now at this line crash JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);        and the crash is org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Bunle of Thanks bro..issue is resolved..the issue is not in the code..the issue is in the device..when i change my device it's run perfect..thnaks alot thanks thanks thanks :)..